# Are there any books that teach text-to-image generation?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-generation, resource-request

I read some of the research papers about text-to-image generation using Imagen, DALL-E 2, etc. but they are heavily scientific and I don't understand a lot of their concepts, so I was wondering are there any books that teach text-to-image generation for beginner ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no books have been released specifically on Diffusion models. Newer versions of [books](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/generative-deep-learning/9781098134174/) on generative models are planned for release in 2023, which probably will include diffusion models. One of the reasons is that the research on these models is still very new. If you want to get into these models, I suggest you start with some blog posts on diffusion models. These will most likely be quite doable and give you a basic overview.

Comment: Also suggest starting with some colab scripts - there are a variety of them, and they allow you to start with a working version and pick it apart to understand how the top level components fit together